# How to make a Pointed Button Shape?

Tags: css

i'm trying to make a pointed button with a after effect but its still seems a bit off

Here is the required button image

[image]

and here is my code

```
.archive #wrap .related-tags .pointed a:after{
content: "";
width: 2.2rem;
height: 2.1rem;
display: inline-block;
position: absolute;
background-color: lightgrey;
right: 2px;
top: 8px;
transform: translateX(1rem) rotate(45deg);
border-top-right-radius: 0px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
z-index: -1;}
```

Here is the html

```
<ul class="related-tags"><li class="pointed"><a class="" href="/category/spring-persistence/tag/jpa">JPA (32)</a></li>
    </ul>
```

fiddle link:

https://jsfiddle.net/8o16sL70/

Comment: Can you update your question with a [mre] of your code including the relevant HTML?

Comment: @AStombaugh yes i added html can you please check it now?

Comment: Hello @syedashar321 it would be very helpful to reproduce your problem for ourselves. That is what an MRE ensures. The code you provided does not reproduce the problem, but if you are able to add in the relevant code to do so, preferably as a code snippet (a tool inside the editor) we will be able to help much more effectively.

Comment: @MFerguson fiddle link is added